# How to push to array only new checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to build system that will recognize when new checkbox is checked, once the checkbox is checked, the user will have to choose one of the options: `left`, `right`, `all`.

Once one of the three is chosen, the checked checkboxes will be pushed into their specific array. (`all[], right[], left[]`)

**The problem:**

Lets assume I check checkbox number 1, and click `all`.

```
Debugging:
all["1"]
```

then I check checkbox number 3, and click `left`.

I will get the following debugging:

```
Debugging:
all["1"]
left["1", "3"]
```

Desired result:

```
all["1"]
left["3"]
```

I want `left[]` array to get only the **new** checkbox checking, but without unchecking the checkboxes.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/gOwRWPm?editors=1111)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Adding each checked checkbox to array
    let checked = [], all = [], left = [], right = [];
    $box = $('.ppom-check-input');
    $box.on('change', function() {
        checked = $box.filter(':checked').map((i,c) => c.value).get();
        $('#choose').addClass('active');
        console.log( checked );
    });
    
    //Push the value to array
    $('.all,.left,.right').on('click', function() {
        if( $(this).is('.all') ) {
            all = [...new Set( all.concat(checked) )];
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        } else if( $(this).is('.left') ) {
            left = [...new Set( left.concat(checked) )];
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        } else if( $(this).is('.right') ){
            right = [...new Set( right.concat(checked) )];
            $('#choose').removeClass('active');
        }
        console.log( 'all',all, 'left', left, 'right', right );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="ppom-check-input" />
1
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="ppom-check-input" />
2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="ppom-check-input" />
3
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="ppom-check-input" />
4
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" class="ppom-check-input" />
5
<br/>


<div id="choose">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="left">left</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="right">right</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all">all</a>
</div>
```

How can I push to an array **new** values only (not all checked checkboxes)?

Comment: so everytime you click on any checkbox only the new checked should be added in any of three arrays ?

Comment: @Swati exactly, but I can't figure out the logic/approach to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do above is giving some `class` to checkboxes whenever its checked using `addClass("selected_new")` then remove same only when any of `a` tag is clicked then only checkboxes which is newly selected will be added in array.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Adding each checked checkbox to array
  let checked = [],
    all = [],
    left = [],
    right = [];
  $box = $('.ppom-check-input');
  $box.on('change', function() {
    //if checked then only
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      //added new class
      $(this).addClass("selected_new")
      //or
      //$(this).attr("data-selected", "selected_new")
    }
    //or [data-selected=selected_new]:checked
    checked = $box.filter('.selected_new:checked').map((i, c) => c.value).get();
    $('#choose').addClass('active');

  });
  $('.all,.left,.right').on('click', function() {
    console.clear()
    //remove class once any link is clicked
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeClass("selected_new")
    //or
    //$("input[type=checkbox]").attr("data-selected", "")
    if ($(this).is('.all')) {
      all = [...new Set(all.concat(checked))];
      $('#choose').removeClass('active');
    } else if ($(this).is('.left')) {
      left = [...new Set(left.concat(checked))];
      $('#choose').removeClass('active');
    } else if ($(this).is('.right')) {
      right = [...new Set(right.concat(checked))];
      $('#choose').removeClass('active');
    }
    console.log('all', all, 'left', left, 'right', right);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="ppom-check-input" /> 1
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="ppom-check-input" /> 2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="ppom-check-input" /> 3
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="4" class="ppom-check-input" /> 4
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="5" class="ppom-check-input" /> 5
<br/>


<div id="choose">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="left">left</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="right">right</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="all">all</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bit dirty to use classes for that. I'd recommend to use a data property for it instead.

Comment: @MarkBaijens what do you mean? is it bad practice?

Comment: @Yotam I wouldn't call it really bad, but using data properties is better for sure. If someone decide to use and write some styling on a `selected_new` class in the future then this styling would also be applied to the newly checked check boxes. Therefore I think you should use data properties instead for cases where you want to store data with an element. That is what data properties are for after all.

Comment: Updated with that as well . @Yotam use any of the two options .

Comment: @MarkBaijens I agree with you on that part . Updated with that as well.

Comment: @Swati Just a tip. Jquery has a [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function to the set data properties